# On a service interface, expose doSomethingOnUser(user: User) or doSomethingOnUser(userId: String)

Tags: java, scala, haskell

I'm using Scala in this question but I'm also ok for an answer in Java or any other language.

---

I can expose a service with the following:

```
def doSomethingOnUser(user: User): Result
```

**The problem is:** perhaps in the implementation it is not required that the full user is loaded, and that simply using the userId would be enough, so the client may not have to provide a full user and avoid an unnecessary DB call.

```
def doSomethingOnUser(userId: String): Result
```

**The problem is:** maybe the interface client side already loaded a full user for some reason, and then it calls this method using `doSomethingOnUser(loadedUser.getId())`
So in the service implementation we now only have the userId while loading the full object could be required: this would lead to loading the object both in the client side, and on the service implementation.

Both possibilities seems to have drawbacks. An easy solution could be to expose both methods so that according to the context and the data you already loaded, you can use either one or the other.

---

This works fine until you add many method attributes.

You can end up with a service interface being:

```
def sendDocumentToUser(document: Document,user: User): Result
def sendDocumentToUser(documentId: String,user: User): Result
def sendDocumentToUser(document: Document,userId: String): Result
def sendDocumentToUser(documentId: String,userId: String): Result
```

---

I just wonder what is your opinion on this subject, what works the best in your experience to get a clean interface on which the client doesn't have to know which method is the best to call for performance considerations, without doing unnecessary DB calls.

Using functional programming languages like Scala ou Haskell, is there some data structure available so that we can make this stuff easier?

And Java, would it be possible?

I'm thinking of using something like that in Scala:

```
def sendDocumentToUser(document: Either[Document,String],user: Either[User,String]): Result
```

As om-nom-nom said: it's not really elegant to use, so any data structure more appropriate would be welcome (one that lazy fetch the object from DB if it was not provided fully loaded like the client for exemple?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot enforce something on implementation, leave it outside of interface (and thus, use userId). For me, `doSomethingOnUser(loadedUser.getId())` is thousand times bettern than

```
def sendDocumentToUser(document: Either[Document,String],
                       user: Either[User,String]): Result
```

You're obligating every client of interface and implementations to call your method for a live long as

```
sendDocumentToUser(Right("doc"), Left(user))
```

It is unreadable clutter, please, don't.

Define your interface as

```
def sendDocumentToUser(document: String, user: String): Result
```

If implementation would need to use already loaded doc and user, they might define their own overloads with back off to stock `sendDocumentToUser`.

```
class SomeImplementation extends YourInterface {
   def sendDocumentToUser(document: Document, user: User) = {
     this.sendDocumentToUser(document.getId, user.getId)
   }
   // ....
}
```

If you really really don't want your users to write `.getId`, define two implicit methods `User => String` and `Document => String`, although I wouldn't do this.

Comment: After rethinking my (deleted) comment a bit, I'm starting to agree with this approach more.  `Either` seems more natural as the result of a function and not as an input to a function.

Comment: I know it's not really readable that's why I'd like to know if there is a data structure more appropriate than Either to do that.

Comment: On your SomeImplementation, if the client calls it with already loaded objects, the objects will be loaded again which means 4 db fetches instead of 2 required (if the sendDocumentToUser(id,id) method implementation loads the objects too)

Comment: then nothing stops you from inverting code in SomeImplementation:  `sendDocumentToUser(id, id) -> preload objects -> feed them to sendDocumentToUser(obj, obj)` where main logic resides. As for datastructures, I don't know any (Option is not an option, IMO)

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution would be to define a case class that will serve as the single param to the function and then do pattern matching in the function to determine how to proceed based on what was supplied.  Could look something like this:

```
case class Inputs(userId:Option[String], user:Option[User], documentId:Option[String], document:Option[Document])
```

Then the function:

```
def sendDocumentToUser(inputs:Inputs):Result
```

The only drawback to this approach is that there is no way to enforce that you have at least the minimum required inputs (i.e. not `Inputs(None, None, None, None)`).  That means that you have to handle that case explicitly in the pattern match and return an failure result or throw an exception.  Not optimal, but a solution none the less.

You could also structure the function a little differently like so:

```
def sendDocumentToUser(userId:String, documentId:String, user:Option[User] = None, document:Option[Document] = None):Result
```

This way you are requiring userId and documentId and allowing optional User and Document objects if they are present already.

Comment: hmmm I don't really like that. Not more readable than the Either solution and no compile time safety